# Problem migrating dockerized nexus 3.from different VMs

Tags: orientdb, nexus3

The problem is that i can't start Nexus 3.14 after migrating nexus-data folder from other MV. What should I do? The versions are the same. The docker command to start the container is:

```
docker run -p 20001:8081 -u 0 -v /u01/nexus-data:/nexus-data --name abs_nexus -e INSTALL4J_ADD_VM_PARAMS="-Xms2g -Xmx3g -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=3g -Djava.util.prefs.userRoot=/nexus-data/javaprefs" sonatype/nexus3:3.14.0
```

```
2019-08-22 08:15:35,888+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.upgrade.internal.UpgradeServiceImpl - The database model for component is 1.14, but the latest supported by this version of nexus is 1.12
2019-08-22 08:15:35,889+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.upgrade.internal.UpgradeServiceImpl - The database model for elasticsearch is 1.3, but the latest supported by this version of nexus is 1.2
2019-08-22 08:15:35,890+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.upgrade.internal.UpgradeServiceImpl - The database model for config is 1.7, but the latest supported by this version of nexus is 1.5
2019-08-22 08:15:35,897+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.upgrade.internal.UpgradeServiceImpl - Failed transition: NEW -> STARTED
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Incompatible sonatype-work database model detected. Will result in failure to launch. Shutting down.
        at org.sonatype.nexus.upgrade.internal.UpgradeServiceImpl.validate(UpgradeServiceImpl.java:166)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.upgrade.internal.UpgradeServiceImpl.doStart(UpgradeServiceImpl.java:79)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.StateGuardLifecycleSupport.start(StateGuardLifecycleSupport.java:67)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.MethodInvocationAction.run(MethodInvocationAction.java:39)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.StateGuard$TransitionImpl.run(StateGuard.java:193)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.TransitionsInterceptor.invoke(TransitionsInterceptor.java:56)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusLifecycleManager.startComponent(NexusLifecycleManager.java:157)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusLifecycleManager.to(NexusLifecycleManager.java:95)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusContextListener.frameworkEvent(NexusContextListener.java:195)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1429)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-08-22 08:15:35,931+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusContextListener - Failed to start nexus
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Incompatible sonatype-work database model detected. Will result in failure to launch. Shutting down.
        at org.sonatype.nexus.upgrade.internal.UpgradeServiceImpl.validate(UpgradeServiceImpl.java:166)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.upgrade.internal.UpgradeServiceImpl.doStart(UpgradeServiceImpl.java:79)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.StateGuardLifecycleSupport.start(StateGuardLifecycleSupport.java:67)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.MethodInvocationAction.run(MethodInvocationAction.java:39)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.StateGuard$TransitionImpl.run(StateGuard.java:193)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.TransitionsInterceptor.invoke(TransitionsInterceptor.java:56)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusLifecycleManager.startComponent(NexusLifecycleManager.java:157)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusLifecycleManager.to(NexusLifecycleManager.java:95)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusContextListener.frameworkEvent(NexusContextListener.java:195)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1429)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-08-22 08:15:35,937+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Incompatible sonatype-work database model detected. Will result in failure to launch. Shutting down.
2019-08-22 08:15:35,938+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -      at org.sonatype.nexus.upgrade.internal.UpgradeServiceImpl.validate(UpgradeServiceImpl.java:166)
2019-08-22 08:15:35,939+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -      at org.sonatype.nexus.upgrade.internal.UpgradeServiceImpl.doStart(UpgradeServiceImpl.java:79)
2019-08-22 08:15:35,939+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -      at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.StateGuardLifecycleSupport.start(StateGuardLifecycleSupport.java:67)
2019-08-22 08:15:35,940+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -      at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.MethodInvocationAction.run(MethodInvocationAction.java:39)
2019-08-22 08:15:35,941+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -      at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.StateGuard$TransitionImpl.run(StateGuard.java:193)
2019-08-22 08:15:35,941+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -      at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.TransitionsInterceptor.invoke(TransitionsInterceptor.java:56)
2019-08-22 08:15:35,942+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -      at org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusLifecycleManager.startComponent(NexusLifecycleManager.java:157)
2019-08-22 08:15:35,942+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -      at org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusLifecycleManager.to(NexusLifecycleManager.java:95)
2019-08-22 08:15:35,943+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -      at org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusContextListener.frameworkEvent(NexusContextListener.java:195)
2019-08-22 08:15:35,943+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -      at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1429)
2019-08-22 08:15:35,944+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -      at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
2019-08-22 08:15:35,944+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-08-22 08:15:36,009+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusContextListener - Uptime: 57 seconds and 827 milliseconds (nexus-oss-edition/3.14.0.04)
2019-08-22 08:15:36,017+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusLifecycleManager - Stop RESTORE
2019-08-22 08:15:36,019+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusLifecycleManager - Stop STORAGE
2019-08-22 08:15:36,031+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.DatabaseManagerImpl - Stopping 6 pools
2019-08-22 08:15:36,032+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.DatabaseManagerImpl - Stopping pool: analytics
2019-08-22 08:15:36,033+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.DatabaseManagerImpl - Stopping pool: security
2019-08-22 08:15:36,033+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.DatabaseManagerImpl - Stopping pool: component
2019-08-22 08:15:36,034+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.DatabaseManagerImpl - Stopping pool: audit
2019-08-22 08:15:36,034+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.DatabaseManagerImpl - Stopping pool: config
2019-08-22 08:15:36,035+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.DatabaseManagerImpl - Stopping pool: accesslog
2019-08-22 08:15:36,035+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.DatabaseManagerImpl - Stopping 6 instances
2019-08-22 08:15:36,036+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.DatabaseManagerImpl - Stopping instance: analytics
2019-08-22 08:15:36,036+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.DatabaseManagerImpl - Stopping instance: security
2019-08-22 08:15:36,036+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.DatabaseManagerImpl - Stopping instance: component
2019-08-22 08:15:36,037+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.DatabaseManagerImpl - Stopping instance: audit
2019-08-22 08:15:36,037+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.DatabaseManagerImpl - Stopping instance: config
2019-08-22 08:15:36,040+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.DatabaseManagerImpl - Stopping instance: accesslog
2019-08-22 08:15:36,041+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer - OrientDB Server is shutting down...
2019-08-22 08:15:36,041+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer - Shutting down protocols
2019-08-22 08:15:36,042+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.OServerPluginManager - Shutting down plugins:
2019-08-22 08:15:36,043+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.OServerPluginManager - - jmx
2019-08-22 08:15:36,045+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer - Shutting down databases:
2019-08-22 08:15:36,046+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient - Orient Engine is shutting down...
2019-08-22 08:15:36,048+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient - - shutdown storage: analytics...
2019-08-22 08:15:36,133+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient - - shutdown storage: security...
2019-08-22 08:15:36,263+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient - - shutdown storage: component...
2019-08-22 08:15:36,336+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient - - shutdown storage: audit...
2019-08-22 08:15:36,370+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient - - shutdown storage: config...
2019-08-22 08:15:36,551+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient - - shutdown storage: OSystem...
2019-08-22 08:15:36,552+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient - - shutdown storage: accesslog...
2019-08-22 08:15:37,680+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient - OrientDB Engine shutdown complete
2019-08-22 08:15:37,681+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer - OrientDB Server shutdown complete
2019-08-22 08:15:37,685+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.DatabaseServerImpl - Shutdown
2019-08-22 08:15:37,688+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusLifecycleManager - Stop KERNEL
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!